# Missing functions in opencv 3.0 for python/PyCharm

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.4

This is a total NOOB question; I have downloaded OpenCV 3.0.0 (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.0.0.zip) and compiled this for python 3.4. (I am on OSX btw)   I am using the library from PyCharm and a simple test using a Sobel filter on an image appears to be working well:

```
gradX = cv2.Sobel( myImage, ddepth = cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1 )
```

However, when I went to try apply a Laplacian filter following some of the online examples, I found the Laplacian function was not part of (my compiled) opencv. I.e., this does not run/compile:

```
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian( image, cv2.CV_32F)
```

It seems I am missing other definitions as well (e.g., could not find cv2.CV_64F) so somewhere along the line I must have messed up. Looking through the piles of compiler output I cannot find anything that leads to where I went off the cliff.

Using

```
print( dir(cv2) )
```

I can see that Laplacian is part of the module but somehow I have no access to it i.e., python doesn't see it. I did set PyCharm's DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to where all opencv's .dylibs ... anything I missed / can check?

Sorry for the vague question but I am rather stuck with this animal.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the wheel file to install from pip. Download the wheel file from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Should take care of your dependencies and help you out with your compiling issues.

So Windows isn't the issue :)

I suspect you are correct. I don't have access to a Mac, so I can't really replicate. To eliminate PyCharm being the culprit, can you fire up a terminal and run your code? By this, I mean do the steps below (forgive me if it doesn't work in Mac, but in Linux here's how I would check).  If it runs, then something isn't quite right in your PyCharm set up. If it fails to work in terminal, then it probably is a lib dependency issue.

Linux in terminal:

```
/home/user/:~$ python3

>>import opencv as cv2

>>gradX = cv2.Sobel( myImage, ddepth = cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1 )

>>laplacian = cv2.Laplacian( image, cv2.CV_32F)
```

Might have to tweak around on the code to make that work for Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It shows only windows, I am on OS X (forgot to mention that and have updated my original posting).   What do you think are the underlying issues I have, lib to lib dependencies?